# 'list' object has no attribute 'winType'

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm trying to run a python script but I get this error. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'winType'`:

[image]

The actual contents of the file are:

```
import time
import pylsl
import bci.open_bci_v3 as bci


#from random import random as rand
from pylsl import StreamInfo, StreamOutlet
from psychopy import prefs
prefs.general['audioLib'] = ['pygame']
from psychopy import visual, core, sound 

import esys_cfg

NUM_CHANNELS = 8
SAMP_RATE = 100

info = StreamInfo('OpenBCI', 'EEG', NUM_CHANNELS, SAMP_RATE, 'float32', 'myuid34234')
outlet = StreamOutlet(info)

#funtion call to start displaying images
#def displayStimuli
# for file in os.listdir('directory'):
# for i in range(0,len(images)):

# def display(files, .....):
#   ex: file_name = ['/dir/dir2/img.png']

window = visual.Window([512, 512])

cfg = esys_cfg.create_config('../stimulus-config/test.yml')
print(cfg.trial_order)
#trial_order = ['one', 'two', 'one']

for element in cfg.trial_order: #loop through all elements in array trial_order
  imageIndex = 0
  for imageIndex in range(len(cfg.trials[element].files)):

    stimulis = cfg.trials[element].stimuli_folder + '/' +   cfg.trials[element].files[imageIndex]
    showStim = visual.ImageStim(window, stimulis)
    showStim.draw([window])
    window.flip()
    core.wait(2.0)
```

How can I correct this and run the program?

Comment: Try to change `showStim.draw([window])` to `showStim.draw(window)`

Comment: You should copy and paste the error instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises in the line

```py
showStim.draw([window])
```

which should read

```py
showStim.draw(window)
```

and if you only have one window, simply do

```py
showStim.draw()
```

which draws in the window that `showStim` was given as argument at initialization. BTW, initializing a psychopy stimulus is computationally heavy (easily takes a few hundred milliseconds), so do it once at the beginning of the script and then update the relevant aspect during runtime. In your case, do this:

```py
showStim = visual.ImageStim(window)  # initialize the stimulus
for element in cfg.trial_order: #loop through all elements in array trial_order
  imageIndex = 0
  for imageIndex in range(len(cfg.trials[element].files)):
      stimulis = cfg.trials[element].stimuli_folder + '/' +   cfg.trials[element].files[imageIndex]
      showStim.image = stimulus  # update the image
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have only one window you could use:

```
showStim.window = window # stimulus is now drawn to window 
showStim.draw()
```

If you have more than one window you can pass the relevant window as a parameter (The brackets in your code are redundant).

```
# Note that this just changes **default** window for stimulus.
showStim.draw(win1)
showStim.draw(win2)
```